# Getting 'segmentation fault' after using self-made init function

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, memory, ini

I am making an INI parser for C. What is happening is that I will call `ini_init()` in `SECTION_OPEN` to help with creating a new INI struct, and I will get a segmentation fault. I am known for putting many memory leaks in my code, but I don't know what I am missing.

I have tried:

- Removing the mallocs in `ini_init()`, which gives a segmentation fault immediately, something I also don't get, since I haven't even tried adding any values yet.

ini.c:

```
#include <ini.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Global functions
// Sets up new struct INI * variable
struct INI * ini_init() {
    struct INI * newINI;

    newINI->variablesPtr = 0;
    newINI->subSectionsPtr = 0;
    newINI->variables = malloc(sizeof(struct variable));
    newINI->subSections = malloc(sizeof(struct INI *));

    // Sets section name to Global, so we can still grab variables outside of a section
    newINI->sectionName = NULL;
    newINI->prevSection = NULL;

    return newINI;
}

// Interprets an INI file, with syntax defined in ../include/ini.h
struct INI * interpret(struct INI * ini, char * filePath) {
    // Loop Variables    
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    FILE * iniFile = fopen(filePath, "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), iniFile)) {
        bool isComment = false;

        // A holding cell for all the bad defaults out there, stay safe out there...
        char holdingCell[MAX_HOLDING_CELL];
        int holdingCellPtr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
            printf("%c", line[i]);
            switch(line[i]) {
                // Move into section
                case SECTION_OPEN: {
                    // The code that crashes
                    struct INI * newSection = ini_init();
                    if (line[i+1]==SUBSECTION) {
                    //     //ini->subSections =  realloc(ini->subSections, sizeof(struct INI *) * ini->subSectionsPtr+1);

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                    break;
                }
                // Set sectionName
                case SECTION_CLOSE: {
                    // ini->sectionName = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(holdingCell));
                    // strcpy(ini->sectionName, holdingCell);
                    break;
                }
                // Skips to new line
                case COMMENT: {
                    isComment = true;
                    break;
                }
                // Gets names and values
                default: {
                    holdingCell[holdingCellPtr] = line[i];
                    holdingCellPtr++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isComment == true)
                break;
        }
    }

    fclose(iniFile);

    // Loop back to beginning
    while(ini->prevSection != NULL) {
        ini = ini->prevSection;
    }

    return ini;
}
```

ini.h:

```
#ifndef SEAWARE_INI_H
#define SEAWARE_INI_H

#define MAX_HOLDING_CELL 255
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 255

// Syntax
#define ESCAPE '\\'
#define SECTION_OPEN '['
#define SUBSECTION '.'
#define SECTION_CLOSE ']'
#define VARIABLE_CALL '%'
#define COMMENT ';'
#define EQUALS '='

// Only one variableType for each variable
struct variable {
    char * variableName;
    union value {
        int num;
        char * str;
        float decimal;
    };
    enum variableType {
        NUMBER,
        STRING,
        DECIMAL
    } variableType;
};

// The magic...
struct INI {
    // If NULL, you are global
    char * sectionName;
    struct INI ** subSections;
    struct variable * variables;
    int subSectionsPtr;
    int variablesPtr;
    struct INI * nextSection;
    struct INI * prevSection;
};

struct INI * ini_init();
struct INI * interpret(struct INI * ini, char * filePath);

#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ini.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct INI * ini = ini_init();
    ini = interpret(ini, "./test.ini");
    // sectionName Test
    //printf(ini->sectionName);

    free(ini);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well.. `newINI` is not allocated, but you are trying to dereference and populate it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wow, i really missed that. I told you I was bad with memory leaks lol